# ActionBar home Button - how to set from API 11

Tags: android, android-actionbar

my android source code is set for min sdk version 11 and target sdk is 17.

this command wont run under api 11:

```
getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
```

as i understand pre api 14 the home button is automatically enabled.  but again my source is on api 11 and i expect it to run on everything onward.  How can i set this so if a user has jellybean then i can enable the home button for them ? or can i do this in xml somehow?

I've already tried the following using targetapi annotation:

```
@TargetApi(14)
public void yourMethod() {
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 14) {
        getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
    }
}
```

but setHomeButtonEnabled is not recognized still.    Do i need to reflect to get this to work ?

Comment: What about the annotation:
@SuppressLint("NewApi")

Comment: doesn't work in my case, i tried.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> but setHomeButtonEnabled is not recognized still

Set your build target to API Level 14 or higher (Project > Properties > Android). This will allow you to reference that method. This will not harm your ability to work on earlier Android versions.

That being said, bear in mind that there are very few devices running API Levels 11-13.

Comment: Hi. I need the code to run on Api 11 and hire. If I set the build to 14 then I can only run on 14 and hire.

Comment: @j2emanue: "If I set the build to 14 then I can only run on 14 and hire" -- no, it does not. The build target has no effect on what verisons of Android your app will run on. `android:minSdkVersion` does, but I did not tell you to change that. What *could* cause your app problems is if you try calling methods like `setHomeButtonEnabled()` on older devices, which is why you wrap such calls in version guards like in the source code in your question. Also, Lint will point out to you when you are making such calls.

Comment: CommonsWare your a fountain of knowledge im ready to accept your answer but can you tell me what targetApi annotation means then ?  here is the code i have with the min sdk set to 11 but built api set to 14:
 @TargetApi(14)
    public void enableHomeButton() {
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 14) {
            getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        }
    }

Comment: @j2emanue: "what targetApi annotation means then ?" -- Lint will complain when you try to reference classes and methods that are newer than your `minSdkVersion`. `@TargetApi(NN)` raises the `minSdkVersion` for the annotated class or method to `NN`, so Lint will not complain anymore. Use `@TargetApi(NN)` in conjunction with version guards (like the `Build.VERSION.SDK_INT` check in your code) -- the version guard ensures that your code runs properly, and `@TargetApi(NN)` tells Lint that you believe that your code runs properly.